# Using Struct Stat()

Tags: c++, struct, posix

I'm trying to figure out how exactly to use stat() to capture information about a file.  What I need is to be able to print several fields of information about a file.  So..

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
     struct stat buf;
     stat("file",&buf);
               ...
     cout << st_dev << endl;
     cout << st_ino << endl;
     cout << st_mode << endl;
     cout << st_nlink << endl;
     cout << st_uid << endl;
     cout << st_gid << endl;
     cout << st_rdev << endl;
     cout << st_size << endl;
     cout << st_blksize << endl;
     cout << st_blocks << endl;
     cout << st_atime << endl;
     cout << st_mtime << endl;
     cout << st_ctime << endl;
     ...
 }
```

I'm thoroughly confused about how to do this.  Why is &buf a parameter to stat?  I don't care about storing this information in memory, I just need the outputted fields within my c++ program.  How do I access the information contained in the struct?  Is buf actually supposed to contain the returned information from stat()?

Comment: I see, thankyou all for the answers.  They were quite helpful.  Does anyone know how using stdin, stdout, or stderr as parameters to stat works?  These are streams and not files so how can stat populate a struct with data?

Comment: Use `fstat`, which takes a file descriptor as its first argument instead of a path.

Comment: Normally I would do this but the environment is somewhat artificial as this is the OS portion of an architectural simulator I have written.  So when a file is opened by a syscall, I have my own vector to act as a file descriptor table.  Is there a good way to capture the actual file descriptor on machine for a file as it is opened?  If that were the case I would use fstat because no translation would be required between stream stats and file stats.

Comment: You should ask these things as a separate question so more people can see them and so that there is more space to write than in comments.

Comment: Will do. I wasn't sure if it was a trivial question or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, `buf` is being used here as an out-parameter. The results are stored in `buf` and the return value of `stat` is an error code indicating if the `stat` operation succeeded or failed.

It is done this way because `stat` is a POSIX function, designed for C, which does not support out-of-band error reporting mechanisms like exceptions. If `stat` *returned* a struct, then it would have no way to indicate errors. Using this out-parameter method also allows the caller to choose where they want to store the results, but that's a secondary feature. It's perfectly fine to pass the address of a normal local variable, just like you have done here.

You access the fields of a struct like you would any other object. I presume you are at least familar with object notation? E.g. the `st_dev` field within the `stat` struct called `buf` is accessed by `buf.st_dev`. So:

```
cout << buf.st_dev << endl;
```

etc.

Answer (score 4):

For another project, I've whipped up a little function that does something similiar to what you need. Take a look at [sprintstatf](https://github.com/hpc/sprintstatf).

Here's an example of usage:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "sprintstatf.h"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *outbuf = (char *)malloc(2048 * sizeof(char));
    struct stat stbuf;
    char *fmt = \
        "st_atime (decimal) = \"%a\"\n"
        "st_atime (string)  = \"%A\"\n"
        "st_ctime (decimal) = \"%c\"\n"
        "st_ctime (string)  = \"%C\"\n"
        "st_gid   (decimal) = \"%g\"\n"
        "st_gid   (string)  = \"%G\"\n"
        "st_ino             = \"%i\"\n"
        "st_mtime (decimal) = \"%m\"\n"
        "st_mtime (string)  = \"%M\"\n"
        "st_nlink           = \"%n\"\n"
        "st_mode  (octal)   = \"%p\"\n"
        "st_mode  (string)  = \"%P\"\n"
        "st_size            = \"%s\"\n"
        "st_uid             = \"%u\"\n"
        "st_uid             = \"%U\"\n";

    lstat(argv[1], &stbuf);

    sprintstatf(outbuf, fmt, &stbuf);
    printf("%s", outbuf);

    free(outbuf);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/* EOF */
```

Answer (score 2):

This question may be way to old to comment but i am posting this as a reference

To get a good understanding about stat() function ,the reason for passing the stat reference and more importantly error handling are explained good in the below link

[stat - get file status](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code:

- You need `&buf`, with a single 'f'.
- You need to say e.g. `buf.st_dev` when printing, since `st_dev` is a field in the struct variable.

Since `buf` is a local variable on the stack, you're not "saving the values to memory" permanently, it's just as long as that variable is in-scope.

This is how you return multiple values, typically, in C and C++. You pass a pointer to a structure, and the function being called fills in the structure with the values it has computed for you.

Answer (score 1):

`buf` is the structure that stat loads with the information about the file you pass in the first parameter.  You pass `&buf` here b/c you have `buf` allocated on the stack as a local variable and you must pass a pointer to the stat function to enable it to load the data.

All variables of `st_*`  are part of the struct stat object and thus must be accessed via your local `buf` variable as `buf.st_uid`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing is with ctime library. Is designed similar way.
First is to create empty struct.
You have access to object of the struct, but all fields are empty.
Then You use that function (&name-of-created-obiect) and is an adrres to point obiect outside of that function.
Function is designed to store all info to that struct obiect from given reference, and kaboom, you have obiect with ready data to use.

Otherwise,  if You don't want use pointer, then you must use
Obiect = function(null);

With pointer
Function(&obiect);