# (closed) stat : always check the return of the function

Tags: function, return, verification, stat

when I construct a string

```
string s ="";
s = rb.rep + a.chemin.substr(rep.size());
//cout << "s:" << s << endl;

if (s.empty()){
    cerr<<"c++ string is uninitialized"<<endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

and doing

```
if(is_file(s)){
    a.s="ok";
}
else{
      SEULS.push_back(ela.first);
      a.s="SEUL";
}
```

with this function:

```
bool is_file(string &path) {
```

the structure is defined

```
    struct stat buf;
    stat(path.c_str(), &buf);
```

you know if it is a file or not

```
    if(S_ISREG(buf.st_mode)) cout<<"is_file "<<path<<"  "<<S_ISREG(buf.st_mode)<<endl;
    else cout<<"NO is_file "<<path<<"  "<<S_ISREG(buf.st_mode)<<endl
```

another way is trying to open the file

```
    FILE*f=fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
    if( f == NULL){
        cerr<<"PROB fopen "<<path<<endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        fclose(f);
    }
```

the result is returned

```
    return S_ISREG(buf.st_mode);
}
```

I got this result on console

> is_file e/rep_A/1.txt  1
>   NO is_file e/2.txt  0
>   PROB fopen e/2.txt
>   Program ended with exit code: 1

but when I comment

```
//    FILE*f=fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
//    if( f == NULL){
//        cerr<<"PROB fopen "<<path<<endl;
//        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
//    }
//    else{
//        fclose(f);
//    }
```

I got

> is_file e/2.txt  1
>   is_file e/rep_B/3.txt  1
>   lesSeuls de e et de a...
>   is_file a/rep_A/1.txt  1
>   is_file a/rep_B/3.txt  1

PROBLEM:

e/2.txt doesn't exists !!

and if I uncomment

```
cout << "s:" << s << endl;
```

before calling

```
if(is_file(s)){
    a.s="ok";
}
else{
```

That's ok !

I get

> NO is_file e/2.txt  0
>   PROB fopen e/2.txt
>   Program ended with exit code: 1

To result I have to print string s or printing something to get the good string s. it is like concurrent programming.

This is not a joke

Did you meet that?

Thanks

Comment: Something somewhere in your code has undefined behaviour. It's impossible to guess what or where.

Comment: One time with `string s = rb.rep + a.chemin.substr(rep.size())` the compiler said s is uninitialized ... this is not the way or something like that. But I was told that one time so now I do `string s ="";
s = rb.rep + a.chemin.substr(rep.size());` and I try `if (s.empty()){
                    cerr<<"c++ string is uninitialized"<<endl;
                    exit(1);
                }` before calling `if(is_file...`

Comment: The non-existence of a file is indicated by `stat` failing with `ENOENT` error. Looking at `buf` is only meaningful when the call succeeds - otherwise, you are examining random garbage left on the stack by previous calls. Check the return value of `stat`.

Comment: waaouuh Yes ! with struct stat buf; // stat(path.c_str(), &buf); if (stat(path.c_str(), &buf) == -1) { perror("stat"); printf("File name: %s \n",path.c_str());<br/> exit(1); } I get the good result : stat: No such file or directory File name: e/2.txt. I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512434/using-struct-stat Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

When the file doesn't exist, `stat` would fail (with `ENOENT` error), leaving its `struct stat` parameter unchanged. Your program does not check the return value of `stat` call; even if the call fails, the program cheerfully proceeds to examine random garbage left on the stack by previous functions.

That's why the behavior of the program changes depending on what you do before the `stat` call - you merely observe different sets of garbage.